# Reversible resource modification in Java

Tags: java, testing, junit, testng

So, there is a huge java test framework project working with various hardware components. The problem is: the @Aftermethod can't dinamically decide what resource to set back to their corresponding original state/value given an exception/hw failure etc. in the @Beforemethod. This could endanger subsequent test cases that rely on the same hw element states (false negatives mostly).

Respectively, I would like to reverse all the object modifications that happened in the @BeforeMethod before encountering the error. This way I could make other tests more error prone (less chance of getting false negatives).

Having defined an atomic state for every suite is not an option (in my opinion) - too much hassle, would require tremendous code modification, thus setting the atomic state for every object could take a lot more time than it should.

Any suggestions? Do you know any good testing guideline/pattern for this kind of problem?

Edit:

```
TestClass1{

@BeforeMethod
method(){
    resource1.setfoo("foo");
    resource1.setbar("bar"); 
    ...
    resource7.setfoo("bar"); // -> hw error occurs, testmethod1 is not run
    ...
}

testmethod1(){
    foo.bar();
}

}


TestClass2{

testmethod2(){
    assertTrue(resource1.doSomething()); /*fails because some combination of 
    the resource modifications that happened in the previous @Beforemethod 
    in TestClass1 changed the hardware operation in some way. */
}

}
```

Comment: why is handling those problems in the @Beforemethod itself not an option?

Comment: Can you please help edit your question and add a sample to the post that shows what you are talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to handle the atomic state, as long as there is a definite way to reverse the state of resources. For example, adding a counter and a try/catch block in the `@BeforeMethod` may suffice:

```
@BeforeMethod
void method(){
    int setupStep = 0;
    try {
        resource1.setfoo("foo");
        setupStep++; //1
        resource1.setbar("bar");
        setupStep++; //2
        ...
        resource7.setfoo("bar"); // -> hw error occurs, testmethod1 is not run
        setupStep++; //99
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        switch (setupStep) {
            case 99:
                resource7.setfoo("bar_orig");
            ...
            case 2:
                resource1.setbar("bar_orig");
            case 1:
                resource1.setfoo("foo_orig");
            default:
                // Failed on first step
        }
        throw e; //Make sure the set-up method fails
    }
}
```

Notice the use of fall through functionality of the `switch` block.